# Return value from SQL local database to global double variable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to get data from a SQL Server local database. I have created Table with 1 columns buyEURrate type float and the table name is CurrencyRates I have global double variable and I'm trying to set its value the same as the first Row from the buyEURrate columns in CurrencyRates on FormLoad so this code below is inside FormLoad. I'm really new to SQL with C#.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and the this is Windows Forms App

```
 using (SqlCeConnection conn =
    new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\FluksikartoN\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BuroFoki\BuroFoki\MainDB.sdf"))
    using (SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        //commands represent a query or a stored procedure       
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT buyEURrate FROM CurrencyRates";
        using (SqlCeDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
          while (rd.Read())
                {
                    EURbuy = Convert.ToDouble(rd[0]);
                    EURsell = Convert.ToDouble(rd[1]);
                     //Index was outside the bounds of the array. error

                }Table
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Use ExecuteScalar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOmething like this should work:

```
using (SqlCeConnection conn =
new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\FluksikartoN\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BuroFoki\BuroFoki\MainDB.sdf"))
using (SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    //commands represent a query or a stored procedure       
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT buyEURrate FROM CurrencyRates";
    using (SqlCeDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
       while(rd.Read())
       {
           double variable = Convert.ToDouble(rd[0]);
           string foo = rd.GetString[1];
           //do something with variable and foo before going to next row in query
       }
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

This may also work

```
double variable = rd.GetDouble(0);
```

Although I'm not 100% sure GetDouble is an actual function like **GetString()** is

**Edit** 
After double checking `double variable = rd.GetDouble(0)` will work to pull the first column data as a double

Comment: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

but when i click showTableData there is a value in the first Row

Comment: You have to use a loop to loop through values

Comment: can you shot an example im really new

Comment: If you take a look at my code I added a while loop, this will loop through every row that is pulled from your query

Comment: what if i make 2 columns and assing 2 global variable to the first rows of these 2 columns

Comment: Then you would just pull the data based of the index of that column....      **[0]** will pull first column, **[1]** will pull second column and so on

Comment: I edited answer a bit more to handle more columns please take a look

Comment: this code SELECTS the second row of buyEURrate if i have second columns sellEURrate and i need to get the first row of it

Comment: No the code will pull the second column on the first row....when you call this line **while(rd.Read())** thats telling the reader to loop through each row

Comment: so **rd[1]** is on the current row but second column since its 0 based

Comment: You have to edit your query to pull more columns....currently you have **SELECT buyEURrate FROM CurrencyRates** which only pulls one column...try **SELECT buyEURrate, sellEURrate FROM CurrencyRates**

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlCeConnection  conn = new SqlCeConnection ("Server=.;Database=Northwind;User Id=sa;Password=as"))
{
    using (SqlCeCommand  cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        //commands represent a query or a stored procedure       
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT buyEURrate FROM CurrencyRates";
        using (SqlCeDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            double rate = 0;
            if (rd.Read()) // if datareader has rows
            {
                rate = Convert.ToDouble(rd[0]);
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 using (SqlCeConnection conn =
new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\FluksikartoN\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BuroFoki\BuroFoki\MainDB.sdf"))
using (SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    //commands represent a query or a stored procedure       
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT buyEURrate FROM CurrencyRates";
    using (SqlCeDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
         if(rd.Read())
        {
           double variable = rd.GetDouble(0);
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

You first need to Read a tuple using DataReader, if it returns true, you can go ahead and read get actual data.

You can also use cmd.ExecuteScalar() method if you are pretty sure that you want to read exactly first column of the first tuple of your table.

Here's more info at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.executescalar(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: if i make second columns with just 1 row inside that table how to assign second variable to the row of second column

Comment: "rd.GetDouble(0)"  the first parameter of GetDouble function is the index of the column you want to read, starting from 0. So, the index of second column becomes 1, index of third column becomes 2 and so on... Therefore to read second column, you must write: rd.GetDouble(1)